# WCF integration testing with Windsor

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, integration-testing

We've got WCF setup to use Windsor.  Now I want to start writing some integration tests and I'm running into a problem.  I found an article by Ayende http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/06/12/WCF-Windsor-Integration.aspx but I can't find the WindsorServiceHost he mentions.  I even went and looked around WcfIntegration in the object browser and no luck.

Does anyone have a more up to date sample or have a short code sample they can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not find it in standard Windsor installation. It is separate Facility (separate project) which hasn't been released yet but you can download source codes from their [repository](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.Wcf).

Comment: The Wcf Integration Facility is available for download.  Maybe it's just a really old version?  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Shane: Based on main Windsor project page no stable / released version exists: http://www.castleproject.org/castle/projects.html